# Sys undefined for HTTPS url in IE8

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I just discovered a rather peculiar issue in IE8 for a HTTPS link. Every time the page tries to access the HTTPS link, it produces an error.  This happens only in IE8 and nothing else.  Any idea what's going on?  I found some items that said that means the files were not loaded, hence the issue and tried some fixes recommended, but they haven't worked so far.  This is a .NET site by the way.
https://www.beckshoes.com/cart/cart.aspx

```
Message: 'Sys' is undefined
Line: 70
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://www.beckshoes.com/cart/cart.aspx


Message: 'Sys' is undefined
Line: 319
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://www.beckshoes.com/cart/cart.aspx
```

Comment: This seems very similar to your problem -  http://blogs.msdn.com/praveeny/archive/2007/03/27/webresource-axd-going-over-http-when-you-are-browsing-on-https.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a JavaScript error.  Firefox handles it fine, but Sys is undefined in IE8 so I'm guessing that the part where it normally gets defined is missing in IE?

Comment: Yes.  The .net framework automatically adds it, but seems like it chokes on the https path

Answer (score 0):

Use View > Source.

Is the `<script src="...">` coming from the `https` server as well, or is it coming from `http`? IE8 may not be loading the script because it isn't coming from the same secure source the rest of the page is coming from. Take the `<script src="...">` (if it does not include the protocol and server, use the same one the page is coming from) and paste it into the address bar of a new tab, does the script load/download?

Is the `<script src="...">` tag that loads the appropriate library even listed in the source? Maybe it isn't being added because ASP.NET doesn't recognize the User Agent and doesn't think it is capable or something.

Comment: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$template1$ScriptManager1', document.getElementById('aspnetForm'));
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._updateControls([], [], [], 90);
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.Application.initialize();</script>

Answer (score 0):

Sys is part of the Microsoft script library, and is loaded through the WebResource.axd file.

Your page seems to be mostly working in IE 8 for me - have you fixed it?

I see that you're loading the WebResource at the foot of the page - if the calls to initialise are happening before the script is loaded, then that will be what is causing it - have you deliberately moved this to the footer? The scriptmanager has a property to do this correctly: [LoadScriptsBeforeUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.loadscriptsbeforeui.aspx). Setting this to false will move those scripts that can be moved down to the bottom of the page.

I notice you've also pushed the viewstate down there, so you're clearly doing som post processing of the html.

The only other thing I can think of is that looking at your page, you've got an IFrame holding the brand rotator, that is requesting it's content from http://www.beckshoes.com/brands.aspx

You really want that under https as well - that's probably not helping.